# Ripple testnet explorer

Tags: blockchain, ripple, ripple-gateways, javascript, ripple-api

This is Ripple main [Explorer](https://xrpcharts.ripple.com/#/transactions). But where can i find the transactions ledger from wallets on Ripple [testnet](https://ripple.com/build/xrp-test-net/).

Comment: I've been working hands-on on creating a payment gateway solution for the ripple currency. I this `https://developers.ripple.com/xrp-test-net-faucet.html` this is where you can find the test net and develop on it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a variant of viewing the transaction history at a certain address:
http://ripplerm.github.io/ripple-wallet/

Dont forget to switch the network to the test in the upper left corner. Good luck =)

Answer (score 1):

There is a testnet XRP explorer:
https://test.bithomp.com/explorer

Mainnet XRP explorer: https://bithomp.com/explorer

Answer (score 1):

Here you can paste the transaction hash and get the transaction details of Testnet transactions.

> https://testnet.xrpl.org/

Answer (score 0):

This may not be as user friendly as you would want/expect, but you can hit rippled APIs with `curl`.  Here's a way to look up a specific transaction on test net, if you know the transaction's hash:

```
curl -s -X POST "https://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51234" -d @- <<-END
{
    "method": "tx",
    "params": [{ "transaction": "<hash>" }]
}
END
```

Substitute `<hash>` above with your hash.

Follow a similar pattern to build "account_info" or "account_tx" commands.  Etc...

Answer (score -1):

Is https://ripple.com/build/xrp-test-net/ not what you are looking for?

Comment: The asker is looking for a transaction history explorer, and there doesn't seem to be one at that URL.